# Add security to php sessions used for cart _upload or not?

Tags: php, session, paypal, session-variables

I've a php session with the following variables initiated:

```
$_SESSION["multi-buy"] = 0;
$_SESSION["basket"] = array();
```

The characteristics of the session and variables are:

- Only these two variables are stored in the session
- No personal information will go into it - no log-ins, phone nos, addresses, etc.
- No user access given to input directly into the variables
- An integrity check applied before populating a cart _upload command for Paypal
- No additional vars added server/client side
- "multi-buy" will be over-written, checked via if n = integer and n > 1 then discount_cart = x; and only output when creating the cart _upload command
- It's all served over https
- Nothing will be stored in a database (the website is databaseless) so it'll be destroyed when the session expires
- All financial and personal data will be dealt with on the Paypal hosted buy now screen.

So my questions are:

1. Is the session in need of additional security over and above an integrity check on output and what's intrinsic to sessions?
2. Is there a vulnurability that's nothing to do with the information as such, but instead with something replacing the session variable with malicious executable code?

Comment: You look after the session. It lives on the server. Only you can amend it

Comment: I thought this, but think I've been spooked by the word 'hijacking' @RiggsFolly (Thank you)